# Add a string[] to a Dictionary Object C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a Quiz in C#. I tried adding questions into a dictionary...

This is how far I got... Please help.

```
public class Quiz
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string[] Options { get; set; }

    public Quiz(string question, string answer, string imagePath, string[] options)
    {
        Question = question;
        Answer = answer;
        ImagePath = imagePath;
        Options = options;
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, Quiz> GetQuiz() 
    {
        var quiz = new Dictionary<string, Quiz>();
        var questionOne = new Quiz("q1", "What is his first name?", "Elon", "/Assets/emusk.jpg", new string[]{"Peter","John","Mark"});

        quiz.Add("Q1", questionOne);
        return quiz;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. And what's the issue that you are having? Any exceptions?

Comment: What IDE or text editor did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added "q1" also into your new Quiz object.  This should only be your key in the Dictionary.

Change it to:

```
    var questionOne = new Quiz("What is his first name?", "Elon", "/Assets/emusk.jpg", new string[]{"Peter","John","Mark"});
```

A little odd, though, that the answer is not one of the options!

Comment: OP might be considering `Options` as actually the "wrong answers" rather than all options so you don't have to store the correct answer in the object twice.  So, a better name might be `OtherOptions`.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for the timely reply..worked like a charm :)

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the question as answered.